# REGEX_MATCH pattern works everywhere but Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to understand the implementation of REGEX used in `REGEX_MATCH` in Google Data Studio. I have a pretty simple pattern that just won't match in Google Data Studio but will succeed in BigQuery and on sites such as [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

The string to match is of the format:

`some.job.run | SUCCESS: [{"object_1":20}, {"object_2":0}]` (with more items in the list)

In BigQuery I can match the expected results with:

`REGEXP_MATCH(input, '^some\\.job\\.run \\| SUCCESS\\:.*')`

This is accepted as valid in Google Data Studio but will not match, I had previously read that Google Data Studio requires a full string match - which I do get in BigQuery and [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) etc.

Is anyone experienced using `REGEX_MATCH` in Google Data Studio able to shed some light on why this pattern won't match in Google Data Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using legacy SQL (`REGEXP_MATCH`). Try with Standard SQL (`REGEXP_CONTAINS`) and that should fix it.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains